# split array based on value php

Tags: php, arrays

i have a array and i want to split it on based on `type` 
and i have this example

```
    $timeless=array();
    $ontime=array();
    foreach($myArray as $item) {
    if (preg_match("/hidden$/i", $item)) {
    array_push($timeless, $item);
    } else {
    array_push($ontime, $item);
    }
```

i have an array which have 20 record and every records contained a key `prayerType` which is `0` OR `1`.

- 1 for Timeless
- 0 for ontime

Comment: And you need to split it according to the prayerType key? you can cast that value and it will either evaluate to true or false, I think this can be even done in a single line on code, can you please be clearer about what is the input and the expected output?

Comment: If $item is an array then why are you doing preg_match() on it? Based on what you have mentioned, your condition there should be `if ($item['prayerType'] == 1) {`.

Comment: what is inside $myArray? Can you show output of echo "<pre>"; print_r($myArray);? You really need preg_match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use 'prayerType'

```
$timeless = array();
$ontime = array();

foreach( $myArray as $item ) {
   if ( $item['prayerType'] == 1 ) {
       $timeless[] = $item;
   } else {
       $ontime[] = $item;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it by checking its value

```
$timeless=array();

$ontime=array();

foreach($myArray as $item) {

  if ($item['prayerType'] == 0) {

     array_push($timeless, $item);
  } 

  else{

     array_push($ontime, $item);

  }
}
```